# SQL: Copy text file to db with multiple character delimiter

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a file that I cannot edit that uses `::` as the delimiter. I'm using the following sql formula to copy the contents of the file to a postgresql database:

`cur.execute("COPY table_name (col_1,col_2,col_3,col_4) FROM 'file_path' WITH DELIMITER ':'")`

When I execute this code the program throws `DataError: extra data after last expected column`. This appears to be happening because sql is inserting a blank column when it parses the colon character for the second time. SQL doesn't allow the use of multiple character delimiters so '::' is not an option.

I'm wondering if there's a best practice for this situation. Maybe some way to ignore the second colon?

Comment: Why not edit the text file and change the delimiter?

Comment: @SloanThrasher "I have a file that I cannot edit"

Comment: create a new file(for instance, using `sed 's/::/:/g' <oldfile >newfile` ) ?

Comment: @wildplasser ya that's probably the best route. for some reason i was thinking there would be a sql way of accomplishing this. i put some effort into creating a table with a single column of data for each row and then finding a way to delimit with sql substring. there's probably a solution there but my sql skills are weak.

Comment: You could create a holding table with extra columns. That way a null value would be inserted for the data between the `::`. In other words, make a table that will accept the data as if `:` is the intended delimiter, remove the empty columns later, or move to existing table.

Comment: @HoneyBadger good idea. thanks for the help!